# htaccess 301 redirect regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to 301 redirect this format or url

```
mydomain.com/texas/map-of-texas/
```

to

```
mydomain.com/texas/
```

I have a lot of urls of states and cities with this pattern so I need a regex rule but I can't seem to get the regex syntax right.

I have used this and similar.  What am I doing wrong?

```
RewriteRule ^/map-of(.+)  mydomain.com /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: When you enter `mydomain.com/texas/` does it load the correct page normally?

Answer (score 0):

The `^` matches the start of the path portion of the url, but in your example "map-of" is not at the beginning of the url. Furthermore, mod_rewrite paths do not start with a `/`, but directly with the url path.

A mod_rewrite rule that rewrites all urls containing "map-of-" looks like this:

```
RewriteRule (^|/)map-of-(.+?)(/|$)  /$2 [R=301,L]
```

The `?`  means that the match is not "greedy".

The rewrite rule redirects the following type of urls

```
mydomain.com/texas/map-of-texas/
mydomain.com/texas/map-of-texas/123
mydomain.com/map-of-texas
```

to

```
mydomain.com/texas
```

Comment: Thanks Peter - I tried that but I'm still get a 404 error on my mydomain.com/texas/map-of-texas/.